# member count.. Array output numbers?

Tags: php, pdo

I am currently stuck..

When trying to fetch member count it returns as an array, which is not that easy to output when It's a number.. here is the code

Member.php

`public function __construct() {
        $this->_pdo = DB::connect();
    }`

```
public function count() {
    $this->_query = $this->_pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members");
    if(!$this->_query->error()) {
        print_r($this->_query);
    }
    return false;
}
```

DB.php

```
    private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/dbname'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function connect() {
    if(!isset(self::$_connect)) {
        self::$_connect = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_connect;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

How can I output this in the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the data.

```
$this->_query->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: This is already done in the $this->_pdo->query() function.. Can I do it twice?

Comment: from what I see you don't call your `DbClass::query`, rather the `PDO::query` method. So: no. You haven't called `fetch` yet.

Comment: I get the result, the result is correct (3) in this case as test.. but the number returns as an array, and I can't do return array() aka the result.. how can I return the number stored in the array ?? That's all I need help with

Comment: You've a really strange class. Now, from the newly edited question (I hope the last): change the query to `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_member FROM members` and retrieve the value with `$this->_query->_results->count_member`